# How to name an option in settings that allows free input in a list (select)

Tags: website-design, web-app, input-fields, selection

In the settings of a web application, admins can select "custom fields" of different types: number, selector, multi-select, etc.

We added an option that allow user (not admin) to type their own option, just like an "other" option where user are free to input what they want.

We currently added an option for admin to allow free editing named (translation): "Allow create option on the fly".

[image]

Still it's not clear: we could think that it actually creates the option on the fly, making it globally available. In fact, it just allow to add a free text, just like when we have "other" in a form

Comment: "Allow user to add a custom choice to their list." If "user" has a distinctive name: customer, client, teacher..., use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Permettre/Autoriser l'ajout de texte
- Permettre/Autoriser des choix personnalisés
- Permettre/Autoriser des options supplémentaires/personnalisées

Le terme "temporaire" peut aussi être utilisé, difficile sans le contexte :)

Comment: Thank you! Maybe my question was unclear. It is more about the configuration for admins. Admins can tell "this option allows free input" or "this option disallow free input". I don't know how to name this option.

Comment: @rap-2-h yes it's more clear now :)